# Every uncountable set of vectors in a countable -dimensional space is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading book 'Course in Algebra' and i'm stuck on this problem:

Prove that every uncountable set of vectors in a countable- dimensional space is linearly dependent (hence, every basis of such a space is countable).

Any hints?

Comment: hint: in an uncountable set of vectors, there are infinite vectors that are combination of $n$ elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix a countable basis $B=\{b_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and suppose $U$ is an uncountable set of vectors.

Every element $u$ of $U$ can be written uniquely as a linar combination of vectors in $B$. Write "$length(u)$" for the largest $i$ appearing in this combination; e.g. $$length(b_1-2b_{17}+b_{18})=18.$$

- Can you show that for some $k$, there are infinitely many $u\in U$ with $length(u)=k$?
- Now think about the subspace generated by $b_1,...,b_k$. This is $k$-dimensional, so can all the vectors in $U$ with $length=k$ possibly be linearly independent?

---

EDIT: Above, I've assumed that the definition of "countable dimension" you've been given is **"has a countable basis."** As Andres points out below, another reasonable definition you could be working with is **"has a countable *spanning set*."**

This changes the proof only slightly. We now define $length(u)$ as the *least* $k$ such that $u$ can be written as a linear combination of the first $k$ vectors in this countable spanning set *(since we're not starting with a basis, there might be many such linear combinations)*. As before, we must have some $k$ which is the length of infinitely many vectors in $U$. The space spanned by these $k$ vectors has dimension *at most* $k$, so we still get linear dependence as desired.

---

If you're familiar with some basic set theory, it's a good exercise to generalize this argument to show that *dimension is well-defined in general* - if $V$ is a vector space with a basis of cardinality $\kappa$, then every basis of $V$ has cardinality $\kappa$, for any cardinal $\kappa$ (finite, countable, uncountable, whatever).

*The key to this generalization of the argument above is that for any infinite set $A$, the set of finite subsets of $A$ has the same cardinality as $A$ itself.*

Comment: How is "countable dimension" introduced? Given the question, I imagine it is not by "there is a countable basis" but rather "there is a countable spanning set". In which case you couldn't just start with a basis $B$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I've edited to address this. The proof of course only changes superficially if we start with a spanning set instead of a basis.

Comment: Do I understand correcly that this proof uses the fact that countable union of finite sets is countable ?